# How do I pass the php variable through the href of the dropdown

Tags: php, html, href, dropdown

I am fetching the email from the search bar and storing it in $first variable. Later I want this variable to be passed through the href=cn.php attribute. How can i do so? Also please note I am using bootstrap here, but skipped the inclusion text.

```
<?php
$first = $_GET['email'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="dropdown text-center">
<br><br>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="col-4 btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data- 
toggle="dropdown">Select the Subject</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="CN.php?email=' . $first . '">Computer 
Networks</a>
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will look like-

```
<?php
$first = $_GET['email'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="dropdown text-center">
<br><br>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="col-4 btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data- 
toggle="dropdown">Select the Subject</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="CN.php?email=<?php echo $first;?>">Computer 
Networks</a>
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```